# How can i get web site title in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to get the title of a given website address in flutter. Example a website title : `<title>Some Value</title>`. How can i get **Some Value** in title tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `html` package so that you can parse the HTML content of the website. Then you can use `querySelector('title')!.text` to get the text of the `<title>` element.

```dart
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as html_parser;

void main() {
    const html = '<title>Some Value</title>';
    var doc = html_parser.parse(html);
    final value = doc.querySelector('title');
    print(value!.text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Young A, this code worked for me.

Comment: Glad to hear it help.